# How to track a cronjob running on my site?

Tags: htaccess

I have an old Joomla 1.5 site hosted on a shared Bluehost server.
Recently my .htaccess files are being rewritten every 10 minutes, and the site has been black listed.
It looks like some php cronjob.
What is the procedure to track where the file could be? The cpanel provides no features to track malware or any such.

How could I track the source of the problem?

Comment: Your hosting provider's CPANEL does not have a `Cron Jobs Manager` option that allows you to list out your account's Cron job list?

Comment: the list only shows jobs created by the user..
I finally found the culprit, i'll post solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to track the file as it had a modified date of 35 years ago.
One of the better hacks I've had to face. Found the solution here
http://www.itoctopus.com/htaccess-file-being-rewritten-every-30-minutes-on-joomla